# Annotated classes can't be found by Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-annotations

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit testing framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->
    </dependencies>
```

spring.xml

```
    <!-- Auto scan the annotated components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.chicago.home" />

<bean id="test" class="org.chicago.home.Test">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="passwd" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.chicago.home.Event</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Class Event:

```
package org.chicago.home;
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table( name = "EVENTS" )
public class Event {
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private Date date;

    public Event() {
        // this form used by Hibernate
    }

    public Event(String title, Date date) {
        // for application use, to create new events
        this.title = title;
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment_generator", strategy = "increment")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "EVENT_DATE")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.chicago.home.Event]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:393)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:386)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.chicago.home.Event
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes are in the package `org.chicago.home` while you component-scan `com.chicago.home`

Answer (score 0):

Because in the `sessionFactory` bean ,  you declare the property `annotatedClasses` has a value of `com.chicago.home.Event` .However , this class does not exist and hence Spring complaint cannot found it .

Actually , your Event is placed under the `org.chicago.home` package , but not under the `com.chicago.home` package.